# Instance member 'image' cannot be use on type 'UIImageView'

Tags: ios, swift

```
var imageView = UIImageView.self

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D")!, identifier: "Estimotes")

let images = [
    53219:  UIImage(named:"White Glyph 2"),
    59317:  UIImage(named:"White Glyph 3"),
    17068: UIImage(named:"White Glyph 4")
]


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    let knownBeacons = beacons.filter{ $0.proximity != CLProximity.unknown }
    if (knownBeacons.count > 0) {
        let closestBeacon = knownBeacons[0] as CLBeacon
        self.imageView.image = self.images[closestBeacon.minor.intValue] // error gets thrown on this line
    }
}
```

How can I fix this error ? Would this code work or am I going in the wrong direction?

Comment: use var imageView = UIImageView() or an IBOutlet from storyboard or xib, variable `var imageView = UIImageView.self` is not a UIImageView as object is a UIImageView  as class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instantiating a class, you need to use initializer.

```
// var imageView = UIImageView.self
var imageView = UIImageView()

//...

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    //...
        //self.imageView.image = self.images[closestBeacon.minor.intValue] 
        self.imageView.image = self.images[closestBeacon.minor.intValue]!
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIImageView.self is class Type, UIImageView() is initialize the UIImageView.